# when to update the tag @author in PHPdoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

This is really a newbie question.

I'm trying to improve my skills with PHP, so I'm reading the code of some libraries. I noticed that many *PHPdoc headers* (is this the right name? I mean this:

```
 /**
 * @param  $config
 * @return bool
 * @author developer1
 */
```

) contain the @author tag.

Let's say that developer2 makes huge changes to developer1's function and then commits to github. Should developer2 update the @author tag?

What's the common practice?

Comment: If you're looking to improve PHP skills, you should probably use a documentation system that's still maintained - PHPDoc hasn't had a release since 2000. I don't see this as a PHP question, really - it's something you'd determine with the license, your team, and the original author.

Comment: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.author.pkg.html

Comment: The author is typically only the person or persons who originally created/conceptualized the file.

Comment: In my environment, we use @author as the person currently responsible for the code, and attach an email address. That way if there is some sort of issue with the code they know who to send a complaint to.

Comment: @ceejayoz 
1) but you still use that header right? which software can be used to parse it and make automatic documentation if not PHPDOC
2) you are right, I wasn't sure how to tag it. I guess what I chose is not appropriate but I don't know what else to put

Comment: @Mark
so, let's say that one day I can contribute to an open source project, I will live the \@author untouched and I won't add anything about me on the header right? Or should I ask the proj leader for the convention adopted in the proj?

Comment: @wwr Ask the project leader. This is primarily opinion based and will differ from team to team.

Comment: I'm new to a lot of things, SO included. I keep stumbling on very interesting questions closed or put on hold. My quest is: if these quests can not be asked here, can you suggest another website without censorship?

Comment: There's some voices here calling PHPDocumentor dead. That is not true. Last release: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/releases/tag/v3.3.1

Furthermore the question is valid. While PHPDocumentor allows more than one author tag (like the accepted answer states to use), this is prohibited in a _file comment_. It is only allowed in a _class comment_. It makes sense, because only one person can author a _file_. Many persons can author the _contents of that file_ (being the classes or methods)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

phpDocumentor 2 support multiple @author  tags:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @author Styx
 * @author second author
 * @package Application\Model
 */
class User
{
}
```

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/author.html

Comment: thank you! I'm confused about 1 thing. @ceejayoz said that PHPdoc is no more maintained. Is this phpDocumentor 2 its successor?

Comment: @wwr phpDocumentor and Doxygen are popular replacements.